# How i can solve "value null" of Timepickerdialog with alarmmanager?

Tags: android

My code is worked, but it has a problem. How I can solve it.
When I choose the first time in timepickerdialog ( click textview time ) . I press OK, alarmmanager will work ok after I press my toggle button. I shut down my app. And turn on again. I click textview time to show my timepickerdialog but i dont choose another time and click cancel. And press Toggle Button, problem is occured. I think because value null of timepicker. I tried many ways to solve it but I cant. Help me please. This is my code 
TextView to show TimePickerDialog.

```
 time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
            mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                    timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    get_hour = String.valueOf(selectedHour);
                    get_min = String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                    if(selectedHour < 10 ){
                        get_hour = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedHour);
                    }
                    if(selectedMinute < 10) {
                        get_min = "0" + String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                    }
                    millis = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
                    time.setText( get_hour + " : " + get_min);
                    savePrefs();
                }
            }, hour, minute, true);
            mTimePicker.setTitle("Pick Time");
            onoff_alarm.setChecked(false);
            mTimePicker.show();
        }
    });
```

This is my toggle button.

```
onoff_alarm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(onoff_alarm.isChecked()) {
                    if (get_hour.equals(null) && get_min.equals(null)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Choose Another Time Please !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        onoff_alarm.setChecked(false);
                    }else  {
                        my_intent.putExtra("extra", "alarm on");
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Set time when " + get_hour + " Hour " + get_min + " Min ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, my_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, millis, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pending_intent);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    my_intent.putExtra("extra","alarm off");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel set time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent);
                    sendBroadcast(my_intent);
                }
                savePrefs();
            }
    });
}
```

I have used SharePreferences like this :

```
public void savePrefs(){
    SharedPreferences sharepreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String hour_set = String.valueOf(get_hour);
        String min_set = String.valueOf(get_min);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharepreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(Hoursave, hour_set);
    editor.putString(Minsave, min_set);
        editor.commit();

public void loadPrefs(){

    SharedPreferences sharepreferences = getSharedPreferences(PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String hour_x = sharepreferences.getString(Hoursave, "");
        String min_x = sharepreferences.getString(Minsave, "");
    time.setText(hour_x + " : " + min_x);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you "shut down" the app, the pending alarms are removed from system. You can check that by the following command in adb -

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm
```

To solve this what you should do is, store the alarm time in a SharedPreferences (easiest way, but you can choose DB table also if you are already using DB) when setting the alarm. Next when re-opening the app from a killed state, simply create the alarm again by reading the time from SharedPreferences (or DB) and using the same same alarm id.

Comment: yes, i have used sharepreferences, i have added in my question, but i still can't  create the alarm again by reading the time from SharedPreferences like u saied.
my LoadPref() in onCreate()

Comment: In loadPrefs() function you are reading the hour and min from SharedPrefs which is fine. Can you please paste the code in which you are re-setting the alarm with these values.

Comment: No, I dont have that code like u say, i just call LoadPref in onCreate and call SavePref in event onClick text view

Comment: As I mentioned in the first post, when you "shut down" the app the alarms are removed from system. So the objective of using SharedPrefs is - when reopening the app to read the scheduled time from SharedPrefs and re-create the alarm again. So in loadPrefs() you should do the following -

1. Read the time (you already did that).
2. Convert it into long millis
3. Set the alarm again with this time.

Hope this helps.